# Drag and Drop xcopy

Tags: batch-file, copy, xcopy, nas

I need a batch script in which I can put files or directorys and they become copied to my NAS. I want to drag the file(s) or folder on the batch and then it does his job. Existing files or dirs should be override and i don't want to get some questions for override or sth. else. Also I want to intigrate this script after this in the Send to dialog of windows. I hope u can help :)

**My biggest problem is the drag and drop function.**

Thank you

PS:
This code I found in internet for drag and drop but I don't understand -.-

```
    @echo off & setlocal
set "Ein=meinedatei.txt"
set "Aus=meinedatei.dat"

if exist "%Aus%" del "%Aus%"
set Zuletzt=-
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('findstr ".rst .pop" "%Ein%"^|sort') do call :ProcessLink "%%~i"
goto :eof

:ProcessLink
if %1==%Zuletzt% goto :eof
set Zuletzt="%~1"
 (echo /%~1)>>"%Aus%"
```

Comment: When you drag a file into a batch script, the full path of the file gets stored in `%1`. (If you drag more than one file, they get stored in `%2`, `%3`, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next script shows batch parameter handling; allows up to 255 parameters supplied via

- `copy & paste` (select some files and folders, right click any of selected, choose *Copy*. Then right click the batch file, choose *Paste*), or
- `drag & drop` (procedure conformable to the one mentioned above), or
- using `sendto` menu, if you have placed the `.bat` file (or its shortcut) into the `shell:sendto` folder, or
- line parameters, e.g. `drag-drop_30401166.bat files "b c"`.

You could replace `echo folder`, `echo   file` and `echo unknown` lines with code snippets suitable for your requirement (e.g. `xcopy`, `copy`, `robocopy` etc).

```
@echo OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions
echo(
echo before any shift [%~0] [%~1] [%~2] [%~3] [%~4]
echo   all %%* = %*
echo(
set /A "ii=1"
:loopfor
  If exist "%~1\" (
      echo folder  %%%ii% = %1  
  ) else (
      If exist "%~1" (
          echo   file  %%%ii% = %1
      ) else (
          echo unknown %%%ii% = %1
      )
  )
  SHIFT
  set /A "ii+=1"
  if not [%1]==[] goto :loopfor
echo(
shift
echo after all shifts [%~0] [%~1] [%~2] [%~3] [%~4]
echo   all %%* = %*
pause
goto :eof
```

**Output sample**:

```
before any shift [D:\bat\StackOverflow\drag-drop_30401166.bat] [D:\bat\runcmd.vb
s] [D:\bat\crlferror.bat] [D:\bat\UnASCII Names] [D:\bat\Unusual Names]
  all %* = D:\bat\runcmd.vbs D:\bat\crlferror.bat "D:\bat\UnASCII Names" "D:\bat
\Unusual Names"

  file  %1 = D:\bat\runcmd.vbs
  file  %2 = D:\bat\crlferror.bat
folder  %3 = "D:\bat\UnASCII Names"
folder  %4 = "D:\bat\Unusual Names"

after all shifts [] [] [] [] []
  all %* = D:\bat\runcmd.vbs D:\bat\crlferror.bat "D:\bat\UnASCII Names" "D:\bat
\Unusual Names"
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Output (parameters supplied in command line):

```
==>drag-drop_30401166.bat files "b c"

before any shift [drag-drop_30401166.bat] [files] [b c] [] []
  all %* = files "b c"

folder  %1 = files
unknown %2 = "b c"

after all shifts [] [] [] [] []
  all %* = files "b c"
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~0` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
:a
cls
set /p file=::drag and drop file you want to copy here::
if not exist "%file%" echo file does not exist && pause && goto :a
set /p dest=Destination path/folder:
if not exist "%dest%" echo path does not exist && pause && goto :a
copy /y %file% %dest%
if %errorlevel%==0 echo copy successful && pause && goto :a
echo copy failed.
pause
goto :a
```

Also, if you want to easily include a path/drive/folder in your send to menu:
1)open cmd and type: `start %appdata%\microsoft\windows\sendto` 
2)right-click in the folder interior and select new and click shortcut and type the location of the item in the dialog.